# Definition of deterministic matrix

Tags: probability

What is the definition of a deterministic matrix? It seems stupid but I cannot find it anywhere.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Deterministic matrix is a matrix that doesn't include any random elements. More precisely, a matrix $A \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}$ is a deterministic matrix, iff for all $i=1, \dots, m$ and $j=1, \dots n$ the values $A_{ij}$ are not random, i.e. they take a certain value with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)